# Why is my paragraph element displaying behind a background color

Tags: html, css

So im making a website for a school project and all was hunky dory until i tried to put a paragraph element in and it displays above the title text behind the background color

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#logotext {
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Doppio One';
  margin-left: 25px;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

#nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

li a:hover {
  color: #fc9516;
}

.darkwrap {
  background-color: #414a4c;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.active {
  color: #22cc25;
}

#clock {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  font-family: Rajdhani;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container darkwrap">
  <div id="logotext">
    <h1>JF Web Design</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- Navigation Bar -->
  <nav>
    <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="TestIndex.html">&nbsp;Page 1&nbsp;</a></li>
      <li><a href="TestIndex2" class="active">&nbsp;About&nbsp;</a></li>
      <li><a href="">&nbsp;Page 3&nbsp;</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</div>

</header>

<span id="clock"></span>
<p>
  Hello
</p>

<footer></footer>
```

i usedchrome to highlight the faulty element so its clear whats happening here its literall positioned at the top behind the bg color 
[Console Highhlighted element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKV6L.png)

Comment: Your `head` tag should close waaay before you start inserting HTML into the page, preferably after the `meta` tags

Comment: it still doesnt work @yomisimie

Comment: Is there a .jpeg that you can include so that the problem becomes clear?

Comment: Remove the positioning on the container div.

Answer (score 1):

`.darkwrap` is `position: fixed`.

This takes it out of normal flow and locks its position relative to the viewport.

The rest of the content is laid out as normal as if the `.darkwrap` element didn't exist … so it ends up covered up by it.

You could use margins to compensate for the space covered up by `.darkwrap` when the viewport is scrolled to the top. I would simply avoid using `position: fixed` in the first place: The benefits of having the menu on screen all the time very rarely outweigh the drawback of using up all that vertical space all the time.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `float: left` and `float:right` please remember to add `clear:both` to the next element on the website. Here is fixed code:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jKRqLz

Comment: thats helpful to know however i dont want it to be within that grey box thats just the title bit

Comment: Can you look in my updated codepen now? Thats the point you want to achieve?